# Wikipedia definition of Image in Category theory applied to Set

Tags: category-theory, universal-property

According to Wikipedia, the image of a morphism $f:A \to B$ is a monomorphism $m:I \to B$ for which there is some $e:A \to I$ with $f=m\circ e$, and such that the following universal property is verified: if there is another monomorphism $m':I' \to B$ for which there is an $e':A \to I'$ such that $f=m' \circ e'$, then, there is a unique morphism $h:I \to I'$ making the following diagram commute:

[image]

Now, I tried applying this definition to the category of sets:

Let $f:A \to B$ be a function. The obvious choices are:

- $I=\text{Im}(f)$
- $e$ is the (codomain) restriction of $f$ to its image
- $m$ is the inclusion of the image of $f$ to $B$.

The problem arises when I want to find a choice of $h$.
Since it has to be
$h(e(a))=e'(a)$, it is $h(f(a))=e'(a)$. But then, this is not necessarily well defined, because it could be the case that there are $a,a'\in A$ such that $f(a)=f(a')$ but $e'(a) \neq e'(a')$, right?

What am I missing here? Could it be the case that Set does not admit images in the categorical sense? That would be so unintuitive.

Comment: You have that $m'(e'(a))=f(a)=f(a')=m'(e'(a'))$, but $m'$ is mono. So, you can cancel $m'$ from both sides $e'(a)=e'(a')$.

Comment: Just a general remark: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage is a better reference than Wikipedia, especially with respect to category theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: your comment is right - as NDB notes though, $f(a)=f(a')$ implies $e'(a) = e'(a')$ by commutativity and since $m'$ is mono, so this issue doesn't come up.

You are correct that the commutativity of the lower left triangle implies that we must have $h(e(a)) = e'(a)$. Note that your choice of $e$ is surjective, so this determines $h$ uniquely. So it's just left to check commutativity of the triangles. For the lower right one you can use surjectivity of $e$ and commutativity of the other (upper, lower left and outer) triangles.

Comment: I don't understand why $h(f(a))$ could be undefined since $I=\{f(a):a \in A\}$ and the domain of $h$ is $I$. After all, $e(a)=f(a)$ for all $a \in A$.